# Combinatorial evaluation of a sum involving powers of 2

Tags: combinatorics

I'd like to figure out how to evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^n (n-k) 2^{k-1}$ using a counting argument. From differentiating the geometric series formula and simplifying, I know that the answer is $2^n - n - 1$, but I'd like to find a combinatorial way to arrive at this.

This is the second part of Problem 1.3 in *A Course in Enumeration* by Aigner. The first part is to show that $\sum_{k=0}^n 2^k = 2^{n+1} - 1$. Specifically, both parts are to be solved using the "sum rule," which states that if a set $S$ is the union of pairwise disjoint sets $S_1, S_2, \ldots, S_n$, then $|S| = |S_1| + |S_2| + \cdots + |S_n|$.

I solved the first part as follows. Let $S = \{ a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_{n+1} \}$. Let $S_1$ be the set of subsets of $S$ that include $a_1$, so $|S_1| = 2^n$. Let $S_2$ be the set of subsets of $S$ that include $a_2$ but not $a_1$, so $|S_2| = 2^{n-1}$, and so on: $S_i$ is the set of subsets of $S$ that include $a_i$ but not any of $a_1, \ldots, a_{i-1}$, so $|S_i| = 2^{n+1-i}$ where $i$ ranges from $1$ to $n+1$, inclusive. Then $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} |S_i| = \sum_{k=0}^n 2^k$ (reversing the order of the sum and shifting the index). But now observe that the $S_i$ are pairwise disjoint and their union is the set of all subsets of $S$ that have at least one element, i.e. the power set of $S$ with the empty set excluded. This has cardinality $2^{n+1} - 1$, establishing the identity.

I've thought about it for a while, but I'm having a lot of trouble finding a similar proof by counting for the second part of the problem. I'm inclined to interpret $2^n - n - 1$ as the cardinality of the power set of a set $S = \{ a_1, \ldots, a_n \}$, excluding the empty set and one-element sets. I'm not sure about $\sum_{k=1}^n (n-k) 2^{k-1}$; I'm thinking something along the lines of number of subsets of a $(k-1)$-element set for $2^{k-1}$ and some choice of one among $n-k$ of the remaining elements for the $n-k$ factor; of course this leaves one element of $S$ left over. Where I'm running into a wall is figuring out how to find *disjoint* sets that involve these choices. Any help is appreciated!

P.S. This is not for a course, it's just part of my own reading. It seems I should know a combinatorial way of evaluating such a simple sum...

Comment: You are SO close. Let's say you are counting subsets including $a_k$, in analogy with your first solution.  There are $2^{k-1}$ ways to choose the guys below $a_k$, and then you have to make an $(n-k)$-way choice. There are $n-k$ guys above $a_k$, so maybe you choose one of those. So you end up with some subset whose highest element is above $a_k$, whose second-highest element is $a_k$, and where there are some number of guys below $a_k$. All of these subsets counted during the $a_k$ phase are different than the ones during the $a_h$ phase when $k\neq h$, ensuring no double-counting.

Comment: Oh, I see - within each subset of $S$ in $S_k$, the second-highest element (by index) is $a_k$, so this subset can't be in any $S_h$ with $h \neq k$. That's pretty - it's neat that a solution ended up being along the lines of what I was trying to do (though I missed that clever step!). Thank you @MikeEarnest!